# windows 8.1 bootcamp screen macbook pro (Early 2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, screen

my problem is when switch from os x Yosemite to windows 8.1

when windows 8.1 is boot the screen make that

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpXidvzBvMM

the screen is work fine when run os x Yosemite

i don't know this problem because windows 8.1 or bootcamp

when restart windows 8.1 sometime screen work fine and sometime it stay that

Comment: you have 2 parts, first one is with graphics problem, but the second part looks ok to me? Could you look in the console-log for the part where you have problems:

Comment: As first try I would reset the PRAM. At boot press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys.

Comment: That's either a GPU driver or hardware problem, or your Mac has ingested LSD.